# Firebase: Can I know rule of `ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL` before signIn?

Tags: firebase

I have implement a `regex` for `email format` in local check,
then call firebase sign in/ sign up api, it return `ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL`, which means the email format I provided is not pass in firebase server.

The email regex rule I currently used is from a pub [validators](https://pub.dev/packages?q=validators):  [code](https://github.com/dart-league/validators/blob/8334b3ffc2dee46de81fab749c70002f9d47d001/lib/validators.dart#L5)

My test simple email is just `aaa@aaa.a`

```dart
RegExp _email = new RegExp(
    r"^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$");
```

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:validators/validators.dart';

class AuthState extends ChangeNotifier {
  AuthState();

  // NOTE: maybe need to use FirebaseApp(appName) to replace default.
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User _userFromFirebase(FirebaseUser user, {bool isJustSignUp = false}) {
    if (user == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return User(
      user.email,
      imgUrl: '',
    );
  }

  Future<User> getUser() async {
    var user = await _auth.currentUser();
    debugPrint('[+] -- $runtimeType: getUser:$user}');
    return _userFromFirebase(user);
  }

  Future<User> signInWithEmailPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      return _userFromFirebase(user);
    } catch (error, stackTrace) {
      debugPrint(
          '[+] -- $runtimeType: signInWithEmailPassword: error:$error, stackTrace:$stackTrace');
      if (error.code == 'ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND') {
        // Login with email not found: to signUp with email password.
        return _signUpWithEmailPassword(email, password);
      }
    }
  }

  Future<User> _signUpWithEmailPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      FirebaseUser user = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      return _userFromFirebase(user, isJustSignUp: true);
    } catch (error, stackTrace) {
      debugPrint('error:$error, stackTrace:$stackTrace');
    }
  }

  bool emailValidation(String email) {
    if (email.isNotEmpty) {
      if (email.length > 30) {
        // assuem email length more then 30 will give false.
        return false;
      }
      return isEmail(email);
    }
    return false;
  }
}

class User {
  const User(
    this.email,{
    this.imgUrl ='',
  });

  final String email;
  final String imgUrl;
}
```

What I would like to do is get this error before user click sign,
is that possible ?

- I just can't find the rule by text or regex.
- Or is there a way to check email only for firebase api?

Comment: before signing in you first need to call signup method to register that email in Firebase Auth, After that you can perform sign in.

Comment: ah, it's fine, my logic is sign in first, if get error of `ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND`, then do signUp. so that it's let user don't need to choose sign in or sign up

Comment: I think ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL also mean user not found. isn't it?

Comment: means email format is not valid in firebase server.

Comment: what regex you have to validate email?

Comment: please add the source code where you are validating the Email address before sending to firebase, I'll try to resolve that.

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhry updated.

Comment: and what email you are sending which is failing?

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhry its just `aaa@aaa.a`, a simple test.

Comment: is it working when you add a correct email, aaaa@gmail.com?

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhry  do you think I can get the email rule from any firebase document ?

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhry yes, it's working. My problem is my local email regex check is not enough, that's why I'd like to know what's the regex rule in firebase server.

Comment: yes I got it, I don't think so firebase provide format, just try with 2 digits after last dot, like aaa@aaa.aa, if it works with firebase then we'll change our regex accordingly

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhry I see....  yes.. hope there's improvement from API or Document. create an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16512) on flutter page.

Comment: so it is working when you add 2 characters after last dot?

Comment: yes.. I need update the email regex in local

Comment: okay, I am writing my answer to update regex

Comment: do you want PR to that [validators pub](https://github.com/dart-league/validators) too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed in comments, we need two characters at end of email address after last dot to match with the firebase email valid format. For that please change your regex to

```
^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$
```

Comment: [Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34212) on flutter page provide link to https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex explained the email regex rule in firebase.